# How to fix Yum install dependency Conflicts?

Tags: centos, yum

I'm trying to install Rabbit MQ in my system.

CentOS Linux release 7.5.1804 (Core)

To install RabbitMQ, I need to install Erlang first and for Erlang I need openssl-devel.

When I try to install openssl-devel through yum, I'm getting the below error. I understand removing the existing libcom_err package could break my system. Hope it's not advisable to remove the existing package and install older one.

So how can I fix this without fixing my breaking my machine ? I tried `--skip-broken`, but that just skips the Package.

```
         Error: Package: libcom_err-devel-1.42.9-11.el7.x86_64 (CentOSrepo)
           Requires: libcom_err(x86-64) = 1.42.9-11.el7
           Installed: libcom_err-1.42.9-12.el7_5.x86_64 (@updates)
               libcom_err(x86-64) = 1.42.9-12.el7_5
           Available: libcom_err-1.42.9-11.el7.x86_64 (CentOSrepo)
               libcom_err(x86-64) = 1.42.9-11.el7
```

[image]

Comment: Look like it's red hat, not centos.

Comment: @TuyenPham   CentOS Linux release 7.5.1804 (Core)

Comment: Do these commands: `yum -y install epel-release` and `yum -y update; yum install rabbitmq-server`, `sudo` if needed, does this help?

Comment: Tried those, didn't work.

Comment: Can you elaborate? What command break and what is its output? and then update to 1st post.

Comment: http://m.uploadedit.com/bbtc/1541348693858.txt

@TuyenPham Updated all my console output

Comment: This comment needs a review, often I would try to uninstall `libcom_err` and then package manager will prevent me from doing that if it will harm the system, I use `archilnux`. I don't have much experience with centos. But if this system is important, I would download right version sourcecode and then compile myself, include all deps.

Comment: The error as best I can see is that your install of `openssl-devel` is attempting to upgrade the `libcom_err-devel` package from the `@updates` repository, but your `libcom_err` package is preventing it.  Is your repository `CentOSrepo`, a custom repository?  Those packages should normally be coming from `@base`.  If you are using a custom repo, make sure it is updated properly and has all the packages.

Answer (score 1):

Can't comment, so adding as an answer. Did you add the epel repo? I tried installing the Rabbitmq-server package and it found the dependencies in the epel repo.

```
Dependencies Resolved

======================================================================================================================================
 Package                                 Arch                      Version                              Repository               Size
======================================================================================================================================
Installing:
 rabbitmq-server                         noarch                    3.3.5-34.el7                         epel                    4.0 M
Installing for dependencies:
 erlang-asn1                             x86_64                    R16B-03.18.el7                       epel                    758 k
 erlang-compiler                         x86_64                    R16B-03.18.el7                       epel                    1.0 M
 erlang-crypto                           x86_64                    R16B-03.18.el7                       epel                     86 k
 erlang-erts                             x86_64                    R16B-03.18.el7                       epel                    2.5 M
 erlang-hipe                             x86_64                    R16B-03.18.el7                       epel                    2.4 M
 erlang-inets                            x86_64                    R16B-03.18.el7                       epel                    800 k
 erlang-kernel                           x86_64                    R16B-03.18.el7                       epel                    1.1 M
 erlang-mnesia                           x86_64                    R16B-03.18.el7                       epel                    700 k
 erlang-os_mon                           x86_64                    R16B-03.18.el7                       epel                    115 k
 erlang-otp_mibs                         x86_64                    R16B-03.18.el7                       epel                     32 k
 erlang-public_key                       x86_64                    R16B-03.18.el7                       epel                    538 k
 erlang-runtime_tools                    x86_64                    R16B-03.18.el7                       epel                    179 k
 erlang-sasl                             x86_64                    R16B-03.18.el7                       epel                    293 k
 erlang-sd_notify                        x86_64                    0.1-1.el7                            epel                    9.1 k
 erlang-snmp                             x86_64                    R16B-03.18.el7                       epel                    1.5 M
 erlang-ssl                              x86_64                    R16B-03.18.el7                       epel                    588 k
 erlang-stdlib                           x86_64                    R16B-03.18.el7                       epel                    2.2 M
 erlang-syntax_tools                     x86_64                    R16B-03.18.el7                       epel                    336 k
 erlang-tools                            x86_64                    R16B-03.18.el7                       epel                    566 k
 erlang-xmerl                            x86_64                    R16B-03.18.el7                       epel                    998 k
 lksctp-tools                            x86_64                    1.0.17-2.el7                         base                     88 k

Transaction Summary
======================================================================================================================================
Install  1 Package (+21 Dependent packages)
```

On another note, I can see that listing libcom_err shows the current version as 1.42.9-11.el7 and the update as 1.42.9-12.el7_5. why don't you try updating the package and let yum figure out the dependencies.

```
[root@centoserv ~]# yum list libcom_err
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos.mirror.infinity.iq
 * epel: del-repos.extreme-ix.org
 * extras: centos.mirror.infinity.iq
 * updates: centos.mirror.infinity.iq
Installed Packages
libcom_err.x86_64                                              1.42.9-11.el7                                                 @anaconda
Available Packages
libcom_err.i686                                                1.42.9-12.el7_5                                               updates
libcom_err.x86_64                                              1.42.9-12.el7_5                                               updates
[root@centoserv ~]#
```

Answer (score 0):

Just install the dependency outside the installation.

example: `yum install libcom_err-devel`

works for me :).